# Ubuntu 14.04.1 Fresh Install - No Sound

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa

I have a fresh install of 14.04.1 on a Asus N550J and I have no sound whatsoever. I have googled and found the original culprit was because the HDMI was set to the default output, this was solved (I think) by following instructions I found on a site by creating /etc/asound.conf and adding the lines:

defaults.pcm.card 1
defaults.pcm.device 0
defaults.ctl.card 1

Now when I run alsamixer in a terminal, the first device it shows is the HDA Intel PCH device, but still I get no sound.

I have also tried following other instructions I found on another site which involved purging alsabase and pulseaudio and then reinstalling them (which also required running apt-get install ubuntu-desktop too as it removed a few things). The only other instruction I can find is to edit /etc/default/speech-dispatcher and change RUN=yes to RUN=no, but it was already set to NO after installation.

I also tried a fresh install with 14.10 but no difference.

I have also realised that the sound works fine with headphones plugged in, just not when they are not.

This is the output of aplay -l:

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC668 Analog [ALC668 Analog]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

Please let me know if there is any more info you need to diagnose, or what other tips you have to fix this

Comment: `asound.conf` affects only programs using ALSA. Tell PulseAudio that you want to use the PCH device (`pavucontrol`).

Comment: I have installed pavucontrol and the pch device is set to master and all is unmuted. But still no sound

Comment: So when you plug in headphones the speakers start playing? (I'm confused)

Comment: No, if I plug in headphones then I get sound through the headphones. But with no headphones plugged in, there is no sound through the speakers

Answer (score 0):

- Check  , in alsamixer,  "speaker"  fader is not muted and try to tweak "automute"  control state (   using arrow keys)
- Check also in pavucontrol ( install it is not present) "output device" tab : you should have 2 ports available(headphone and speaker )
- It seems some people have problem with standby mode : sometime speaker works coming from standby : look this recent question : [Realtek ALC662 rev3 speaker problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/563624/realtek-alc662-rev3-speaker-problem)

Comment: Nothing is muted in alsamixer, in pavucontrol there is hdmi and built in audio - under built in audio there is speakers, analogue output and headphones. By coming from standby the speakers now work fine. Thank you very much. This at least gets the speakers working for now. Do you know of any planned fix?

Comment: It will be fix if  some user(s) take time to report the problem to Ubuntu launchpad : https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/alsa-driver  .

Comment: Done https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/alsa-driver/+question/259340 :)